# Is it ok to close unformatted question?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/8ad8bea3-def5-46dc-93b0-16d90495c51d/view-source) not formatted properly and horrible to read and understand. Can I close this question as "**Unclear what you are asking**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its meaning is clear, and it just needs to be re-formatted, then no. "Unclear what you are asking" doesn't mean it needs to be formatted to be easier to read; that is what editing is for.

Comment: While I agree, it _is_ very tempting to close questions from people who can't even be bothered formatting their text/question to be readable. Not being a native/great English speaker is an acceptable reason to have lousy grammar/syntax. Not formatting is just lazy.

Comment: That is what down-voting should be used for: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." (See [the vote-down privilege page](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down).) I agree that formatting a question doesn't require to perfectly know English, and it should be one of the efforts the users do. To some extend, also being able to correctly expose the problem without to leave implicit things should be one of the efforts users should do.